# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. Issue calling ActionListener from another class

Tags: java, actionlistener

My first draft of my application was that I have the actionListener in the same class as class the one used to create my Jbutton in. this worked fine but I wanted to tidy it up. having a controller class which I create my frame and have my actionlistener in.

controller class:

```
public class Controller extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
GUI GUIClass;

public Controller() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

  //Main
  //create frame 
 // actionListener method below.....


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object src = e.getSource();
    System.out.println("..........");
    if (src == GUIClass.AddBtn) {        //Line 120 where I Have the issue


 }


 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Controller.actionPerformed(Controller.java:120)
    ......
     .......
     .....
```

My gui class********

I declare my buttons

```
 JButton AddBtn, perviousBtn, NextBtn;
```

and here how I add listener to button

```
 AddBtn.addActionListener(new Controller());
```

I tried number of things button I don't seem to getting anywhere, please tell if you spot a silly mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: Well where are you initializing your `GuiClass` variable?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've tried GUI Guiclass = new GUI(); but the action listener doesn't work. sorry if that wasn't what you asked.

Comment: Remember, that when you are an instance variable like that: `GUI GUIClass;` the variable will be initialized to null, so it is the same as doing `GUI GUIClass = null;`

Comment: Well no, that's going to create a *separate* instance. Presumably you want to hook up your controller to *some particular instance* of the GUI class. You need to work out how you intend to do this.

Comment: @Alderath: It's not *quite* the same as doing that - but it *usually* is :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand What I need to do, but no idea how to do it.

Comment: @JamesHunter: Well we have no idea what creates an instance of `Controller`, or what creates an instance of `GUI`. That makes it very hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main form GUI init the actionlistener class:

> Controller c = new Controller(this);

add  the actionlistener to your buttons:

> AddBtn.addActionListener(c);

and in your Controller class change your constructor to:

```
public Controller(GUI g) {
   this.GUIClass = g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever set `GUIClass` to something non-null?  your constructor seems empty, so i'm guessing not.  if not, then you will get an NPE when dereferencing this reference.

Future tip: when you get into a situation like this and you can't figure out the problem with visual inspection, run the code in a debugger (there are plenty of good, free ones out there).

Comment: I don't I ever do,What would I need in my constructor ?